# Error when trying to connect MySQL DB via Spark and JDBC

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I'm having issues when I try to connect my MySQL DB from my Databricks cluster, I suposse that it was a connectivity issue between the cluster and the DB but when I try to connect using pymysql it works, on the other hand, if I do it with Scala and JDBC the connection hangs.

This is how I'm doing the connection with Python using PyMySQL:

```
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

def queryData():
    host = 'host'
    port = 3306

    mysql = {'host' :   host ,
             'user'  :   '',
             'passwd':   '',
             'db'    :   'dbo',
             'port'  :   port}

    connection = pymysql.connect(**mysql)
    cursor = fibo.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Job LIMIT 100') 
    res = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM Job LIMIT 100', connection )
    
    return res
```

And this is how I'm trying to do it using Scala:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.util.Properties

object MySQLSample extends App{
  def main() = {
    val spark = SparkSession
       .builder()
       .appName("FiboConn")
       .getOrCreate()

      val url = "jdbc:mysql://host:3306"
      val table = "dbo"

      val properties = new Properties()
      properties.put("user", "user")
      properties.put("password", "pass")

      Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
      val mySQLDF = spark.read.jdbc(url, table, properties)
      mySQLDF.show()
  }
}
```

I have also tryed to connect using DriverManager this way with same result:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword)
```

Comment: just checking for the obvious. Are you passing the jdbc driver in your spark-submit or spark-shell? (or in sbt as a dependency)

Comment: Not sure about what you mean with passing, in Scala example I'm using  `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")` in order to use the library `mysql_connector_java_8_0_17.jar` I have installed on my Databricks cluster.